# how to make dropdown select a certain value from getting the id from the database?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select

The code below show a dropdown list from using *ng-repeat*. When I edit this entity, I have to make them show a certain value selected already than just showing a whole list. I know that I can put *selected* keyword when I want to select a certain value. 
Then what if I used ng-repeat to populate a dropdown? How can I make a dropdown choose a certain value using the id?

```
<div ng-if="field.name=='ClienteleId'" class="input-group inputFill">
    <select ng-disabled="defaultSaveButtons[$index]" class="form-control inputFill2"
    ng-model="field.value" ng-options="clientele.id as clientele.name for clientele in     dropdown.clienteleOptions  | orderBy:'name'  track by clientele.id"></select>
 /div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of a `<select>` in AngularJS, you need to change the variable that is set as its `ng-model` to one of the values in your options.

In your case, you have `field.value` as your `ng-model`, and your options use the `name` attribute as their label and the `id` attribute as their value. To have one of the items in `dropdown.clienteleOptions` selected by default, you need to set `field.value` to the `id` attribute of the corresponding entry in `dropdown.clienteleOptions`.

Imagine your options and fields look like this:

```
$scope.clienteleOptions = [
    {id: 1, name: 'test 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'test 2'}
];

$scope.fields = [
    {name: 'ClienteleId', value: null}
    // ...
];
```

In your controller somewhere, you would have something like this to have test 2 selected:

```
$scope.fields[0].value = 2;
```

Or to make it more dynamic:

```
$scope.fields.forEach(function (field) {
    if (field.name === 'ClienteleId') {
        field.value = 2;
    }
});
```